# Git track an upstream branch that is not origin

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I have a Git project and my colleagues all fork off of it. I'd like to test out a feature one of my colleagues has built. They merged their changes into their master branch (different repo  address than mine). Locally I'd like to call the branch 'foo' and track their branch from it. This way when I do a `git pull upstream ???` it'll pull their master into my local feature branch... NOT their master into my master.

Currently we are using Git 1.7.9.6.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your repo,

#### Git 1.8+

```
git branch -u remote/master local_branch
```

#### Git 1.7

```
git branch --set-upstream local_branch remote/master
```

That is, if the remote you want to pull from is `remote` and its branch is `master`.  The Git 1.7 syntax still works with 1.8, but the 1.8 syntax is easier to remember.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -t upstream/branch_name` should work. `-t` is short for `--track`. See http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/09/checkout-remote-tracked-branch.html